# Some missing header files like import/cli.h , io/FileOutputStream.h or gpu/StreamManager.h

Tags: c++, cuda, c++-cli, gpu

I am trying to compile a project which is using CUDA but I couldn't get it compile.
I am missing the following header files.

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <import/cli.h>
#include <sys/OS.h>
#include <io/FileOutputStream.h>
#include <mem/ScopedAlignedArray.h>
#include <gpu/StreamManager.h>
#include <gpu/UniPtr.h>
```

I've looked them up on the internet but couldn't find any sources. Do you have any idea about what library should I install?

I've already installed CUDA 5.5 and Nsight. 
Also I am using Visual Studio 2012

I've already added the following lines to include directory and library directory

```
C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.5\common\inc
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\lib
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: certainly `cuda_runtime.h` is a standard CUDA header file.  The `nvcc` compiler driver should find that automatically.  My guess is you are not compiling this file with `nvcc`.  It's OK to use in a file compiled with the host compiler (`cl.exe`) but adding the include paths you did should allow it to be found.  I guess this project was originally set up in linux and you are trying to build it in windows?  Where did the project come from?  If you have all the source tree, the directories like `gpu`, `mem`, etc. should already be in your source tree.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this path to include directorie
`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA 
Corporation\CUDA\include`

If using samples try
 `C:\ProgramData\NVIDIACorporation\CUDASamples\v5.5\common\inc\`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt respond.
since I'm using cuda 5.5 I tried your solution and added C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.5\common\inc to the include directory but there wasn't any luck.

Comment: Did you try the other path ? the second one is only for the include headers of the Sample code, but you should first add the includes of the SDK (not sample code)